# conditional comment are like media queries?How to place condition as in media queries

Tags: css, media-queries, internet-explorer-7

Is it possible to do what we can do with media queries using conditional comments for IE below to IE 9. IE 8 and earlier dont support media queries. What I want to accomplish is if the size of screen reduced to certain size then I want to use  `display:none` for certain elements. and a few other things.

If conditional comments dont cover what I am looking for then how can I accomplish what I am doing using css for IE 8 and earlier. Thanks

Comment: You need to use JavaScript for browsers not supporting media queries. Though I highly recommend not developing for IE8 and below anymore.

Comment: @KilianStinson are u sure: there is no way with css?

Comment: Besides media queries there is no way to detect your viewport size using css only.